# How to track the .net framework methods in "Call Tree" when profiling in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, profiling

I'm using profiler in Visual Studio 2008 [like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/ianhu/archive/2005/12/19/505702.aspx), but when I profiling these codes I can only find the methods written by myself in "Call Tree" view. How can I track the inner/private methods defined in .NET Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do have to ask what is your purpose. Are you trying to find and remove performance problems? If so, any fixes you make can only be in your code. A simple way to find them is to run the program under the IDE and, while it is being slow, pause it and record the call stack. Do this several times. If there is any line of code that appears on multiple samples, those samples are occurring within work being requested by it, so if you can find a way to avoid doing that line of code, you will save a large fraction of time. The call tree may show such a line, but to see how much time it saves, you have to sum over all the branches in the tree where it occurs. You don't have that problem if you just sample the stack.

[Here's a more complete explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)

[Here's a blow-by-blow example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773)

[There are some myths re. performance tuning.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)

Comment: Thanks, I just want to do some investigation/analysis in depth.